# Nested conditional operator interpreted as String

Tags: jsf, el, conditional-operator

In my Java EE 7 / JSF / EL 3.0 project, I need to define the style class of a tag depending of the condition:

- if `x < a`, then the class is `LT-A`
- else if `x > b`, then the class `BT-B`
- else the class is `BETWEEN-A-B`

The only solution I could find is using a nested conditional operator:

```
styleClass="#{x<a ? 'LT-A' : (x>b ? 'BT-B' : 'BETWEEN-A-B')}"
```

However, my problem is that the `(x>b ? 'BT-B' : 'BETWEEN-A-B')` part gets interpreted as a `String` (and thus is rendered as-is instead of actually evaluated).

Is something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm :)
Would you please rewrite your comment as an answer so I can check it as the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<` and `>` are being misinterpreted. If you use `lt` and `gt` everything should work just fine.

**Here's a full list of EL logical operators:**

---

`and` - *Logical operator alternative to (&&)*

`false` -   *Boolean literal*

`le`    - *Relation operator less than or equal to alternative to (<=)*

`not`   - *Logical operator reverse alternative to (!)*

`div`   - *Arithmetic operator division alternative to (/)*

`ge`    - *Relational operator greater or equal to alternative to (>=)*

`lt`    - *Relational operator less than alternative to (<)*

`null`  - *Null literal*

`empty` - *The empty operator is a prefix operation that can be used to determine whether a value is null or empty.*

`gt`    - *Relational operator greater than alternative to (>)*

`mod`   - *Arithmetic operator modulo alternative to (%)*

`or`    - *Logical operator alternative to (||)*

`eq`    - *Logical operator alternative to (==)*

`instanceof`    - *Java Keyword to do a Class comparison between Objects*

`ne`    - *Relational operator not equal alternative to (!=)*

`true`  - *Boolean literal*

---

courtesy of [javaevangelist.blogspot.co.at](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.co.at/2013/04/jsf-2x-tip-of-day-jsf-expression.html)